# Copy data values for another column if matched

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: SHEET 1]

[image: SHEET 2]

Sheet 1 has Month, Day and Year while Sheet 2 has Year and Day. If the data of Year in Sheet 1 and 2 are matched I want to copy the Day values from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2. Is it done by VLookup and how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you expect to see in column B of Sheet2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `vlookup`, however you would need to have your search criteria in the first column from your range to be searched, eg `Sheet 1` as :
_ | A | B | C
--- | --- | --- | ---
1 |
2 | Year | Month | Day
3 | 1988 | 12 | 25
...
Then you could use the formula:

```
sheet2!B3 = vlookup(A3,sheet1!a2:c7,3,0)
```

Yet I prefer `index(match())`, more flexible, and typically with your example, you can use it without reordering columns:

```
sheet2!B3 = index(sheet1!B:B,match(A3,sheet1!C:C,0))
```